# How do i select a .html file and launch it with the <select>

Tags: html

I am Writing an HTML page and have run into an issue where I make a `<select>` and `<option>` drop down menu.

I was wondering if there is anyway I can make this `<option>` open the Html page?

I have tried some things i have found on google and it did not seem to work for this case. Am i going to need to use JavaScript or some other language? I'm not really familiar with HTML or JavaScript. I am fairly new to this.

```html
<html>
<Title> Final Project</Title>
<style> body {background-color: Teal;} </style>
<Head>  <p Align=Center> <Font Size="7" Color=Red> Final Project </Font></p>
  <p align=Center> <Font Size="6" color=Blue> Routing and Switching </Font></p>
</Head>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  a:link,a:visited {
   color: White;
   background-color: Black;
   text-decoration: none;
   target-new: tab;
  }
  a:hover {
   color: #0000FF;
   background-color: #FFFFC0;
   text-decoration: underline;
   target-new: none;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="http://www.weichertrents.com/45777789/?query=cityid%3d46552">The building</a>
</body>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  a:link,a:visited {
   color: White;
   background-color: Black;
   text-decoration: none;
   target-new: tab;
  }
  a:hover {
   color: #0000FF;
   background-color: #FFFFC0;
   text-decoration: underline;
   target-new: none;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="Resources\Floor Plan.html">Floor Plan</a>
</body>

<select>
  <option value="Welcome Page.html">Home</option>
  <option value="\Resources\Floor Plan.html">Floor Plan</option>
</select>

<HR Width="100%" Size="2" Color="Purple"> </hr>.
<Body>
<p Align=Center> <Font color=Yellow><u> Resources </u></Font>
<p Align=Center>
 150k
<p Align=Center> <Font color=Yellow><u> Things to get </u></Font>
 <br>A building        Done
 <br>floor plan        
 <br>office equipemnt computers n such
 <br>security
 <br>networking
 <br>office supplies
 <br>employees
 <br>Server
 <br>terminals 
 <br>chair
 <br>tables
 <br>cablign
 <br>routers
 <br>switches
 <br>Waps
 <br>operating systems
 <br>offices
 <br>licenses for office
</p>

</Body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use javascript.  Change your select tag to look like this:

```
<select onChange="window.location = this.value">
```

This implementation is the most basic way to use javascript to do this, you may want to implement some other controls (e.g. checking to make sure the url is valid before forwarding).

You're going to have to make your `<option>` values valid paths (e.g. `\Resources\Floor Plan.html` should probably be `Resources/Floor Plan.html`).

One other thing to note, if you decide to put absolute urls in one of your values make sure that you keep the URL schema the same.  e.g. Most browsers will not allow you to link from `http` to `https` in this way.  This is because this method is technically a redirect and not a true link.

Comment: Thank you it worked I will have to look for a way to validate the links before forwarding. I also made the paths valid Thank you very much i was stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and the onchange event. You could accomplish this with jQuery or another library, or vanilla javascript.

For example, on your select tag, add an "onchange" attribute "alert(this.value)".

```html
<html>
<Title> Final Project</Title>
<style> body {background-color: Teal;} </style>
<Head>  <p Align=Center> <Font Size="7" Color=Red> Final Project </Font></p>
  <p align=Center> <Font Size="6" color=Blue> Routing and Switching </Font></p>
</Head>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  a:link,a:visited {
   color: White;
   background-color: Black;
   text-decoration: none;
   target-new: tab;
  }
  a:hover {
   color: #0000FF;
   background-color: #FFFFC0;
   text-decoration: underline;
   target-new: none;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="http://www.weichertrents.com/45777789/?query=cityid%3d46552">The building</a>
</body>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  a:link,a:visited {
   color: White;
   background-color: Black;
   text-decoration: none;
   target-new: tab;
  }
  a:hover {
   color: #0000FF;
   background-color: #FFFFC0;
   text-decoration: underline;
   target-new: none;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="Resources\Floor Plan.html">Floor Plan</a>
</body>

<select onchange="alert(this.value)">
  <option value="Welcome Page.html">Home</option>
  <option value="\Resources\Floor Plan.html">Floor Plan</option>
</select>

<HR Width="100%" Size="2" Color="Purple"> </hr>.
<Body>
<p Align=Center> <Font color=Yellow><u> Resources </u></Font>
<p Align=Center>
 150k
<p Align=Center> <Font color=Yellow><u> Things to get </u></Font>
 <br>A building        Done
 <br>floor plan        
 <br>office equipemnt computers n such
 <br>security
 <br>networking
 <br>office supplies
 <br>employees
 <br>Server
 <br>terminals 
 <br>chair
 <br>tables
 <br>cablign
 <br>routers
 <br>switches
 <br>Waps
 <br>operating systems
 <br>offices
 <br>licenses for office
</p>

</Body>
</HTML>
```